# Selenium, python, clicking on a javascript link regularly?

Tags: javascript, python, multithreading, selenium

what should be right way to click on a javascript generated link on a regular time interval using python and selenium bindings? should it be using a thread?

as i would need to continue to process the input data, i need to refresh/reset a timer to continue to receive data, clicking on this given link to do this refresh (and this link is html directly generated by javascript).

best regards

Comment: Where does the `input data` come from?

Comment: it is a web page, containing javascript, that will receive javascript data. I can not operate on this page which is on a distant server, and will use a proxy to log everything coming in. But to receive data continously i must do some clicks at regular time interval with selenium to refresh the timer that it will , due to this clicks never say "too long inactivity, stop transmitting". Clicks will be do on a javascript generated link `href="javascript.void()"`

Comment: Something like [`this`](http://jsfiddle.net/falsetru/4UxgK/show/)?

Comment: yes :) ! but clicking on "activity" will reset timer to zero. EDIT: ok sorry do not see that clicking was reseting timer ! so exactly this kind of behaviour :) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need thread to do this.

Use javascript function [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) to continuously click the link.

For example:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://jsfiddle.net/falsetru/4UxgK/show/')

# Click the link every 3000 ms.
driver.execute_script('''
    // argument passed from Python can be accessed by `arguments` array.
    var link = arguments[0];
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        link.click();
    }, 3000);
''', driver.find_element_by_id('activity'))

while True:
    data = driver.find_element_by_id('counter').text
    print(data)
    time.sleep(1)
```

**NOTE**

If you get error like follow, upgrade [`selenium`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) to recent version. I experienced following error with *Firefox 23.0* + *selenium 2.32.0*. Error was gone with *selenium 2.35.0*.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t2.py", line 12, in <module>
    print driver.execute_script('''return 1 + 2;''')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 397, in execute_script
    {'script': script, 'args':converted_args})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 165, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 158, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'waiting for evaluate.js load failed' ; Stacktrace: 
    at r (file:///tmp/tmpm1sJhH/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8360)
    at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.runWhenTrue/g (file:///tmp/tmpm1sJhH/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:392)
    at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///tmp/tmpm1sJhH/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:386)
```

### Alternative: using thread

```
import threading
import time

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://jsfiddle.net/falsetru/4UxgK/show/')

def click_loop(link, interval):
    while True:
        link.click()
        time.sleep(interval)

link = driver.find_element_by_id('activity')
threading.Thread(target=click_loop, args=(link, 3)).start()

while True:
    data = driver.find_element_by_id('counter').text
    print(data)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: i am stuck on debian stable version, i may not be able to update everything... I would have been interested in a thread solution to see how it was handled with Selenium. BTW i will try your solution :) ! hoping that i do not encoutner the error you cite, thx

Comment: @user1340802, Can you use Chrome Driver? *selenium 2.32.0* + *chromium 28.0.1500.71* worked well.

Comment: that may sound a good idea ! so i will need to check how to change proxy settings for chromium from selenium... i have to search/check how to do that :)

Comment: @user1340802, I added an alternative version that use thread.

Comment: one important question, from `driver.execute`, may i pass something resulting on a `.find_element_by_xpath`? (to get the right element i need to loop among all the `xpath = "//a"` because there is no other `id` and i must first search the right one from an exhasutive search.)

Comment: @user1340802, Yes, you can pass *HTML element* object returned by `find_element_*` to `driver.execute_script`.