# how to import a file into webpage using python

Tags: python

I´m beginner in python. I would like to know how to import a file (.xls or .csv) into a webpage like "http://www.naturfreunde-oberkochen.de/demos/simpledemo/index.php". Instead of manually selecting a file and upload into a webpage. I´m trying to provide the filename through script and import the file into webpage using python script.
In this page source there is something like <‌​/object>. If i click on the button then it is getting data from another js file.
How to handle here to import file.

I´m able to get the page source of webpage but dont know how to move forward.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665072/how-to-upload-file-picture-with-selenium-python or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18823139/selenium-webdriver-upload-file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If you see in that page source there is something like <object id="SWFUpload_0" ......><param name="wmode" .......</param>....</object>. If i click on the button then it is getting data from another js file.